# _asm TBLRDPOSTINC _endasm,

Tags: pic, c, assembly

I am using a PIC18f25K80 and an XC8 compiler. I have included the files from the MDD library. However, after compiling I get the following in the "FSIO.c" file:

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'H:/SPATIAL/SPATIAL.X/SPATIAL.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/SPATIAL.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'H:/SPATIAL/SPATIAL.X/SPATIAL.X'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.32\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=18F25K80 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --emi=wordwrite --opt=default,+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=0 --asmlist --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-download,+config,+clib,+plib --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/main.p1  main.c 
main.c:217: warning: (350) unused variable definition "pointer2" (from line 200)
main.c:217: warning: (350) unused variable definition "pointer" (from line 197)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.32\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=18F25K80 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --emi=wordwrite --opt=default,+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=0 --asmlist --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-download,+config,+clib,+plib --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/FSIO.p1  FSIO.c 
FSIO.c:197: warning: (335) unknown pragma "udata"
FSIO.c:199: warning: (335) unknown pragma "udata"
FSIO.c:201: warning: (335) unknown pragma "udata"
FSIO.c:7120: warning: (345) unreachable code
FSIO.c:7983: error: (195) expression syntax
FSIO.c:8081: error: (195) expression syntax
FSIO.c:8132: error: (195) expression syntax
FSIO.c:8690: warning: (359) illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char
FSIO.c:9359: warning: (343) implicit return at end of non-void function
FSIO.c:9359: warning: (350) unused variable definition "utf16path2" (from line 8691)
FSIO.c:10311: warning: (359) illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char
FSIO.c:10566: warning: (359) illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char
FSIO.c:11104: warning: (343) implicit return at end of non-void function
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: *** [build/default/production/FSIO.p1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:163: recipe for target 'build/default/production/FSIO.p1' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'H:/SPATIAL/SPATIAL.X/SPATIAL.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:75: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'H:/SPATIAL/SPATIAL.X/SPATIAL.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 5s)
```

For some reason it doesn't like the following

```
_asm TBLRDPOSTINC _endasm
```

Comment: It looks like it has trouble with a lot more than just that. In any case, without source code I don't see how we can help.

Comment: @NickJohnson I am not calling any functions from main yet. The FSIO.c file is too big to include the code by editing the question. Can I include a file somehow?

Comment: You must be doing _something_ in main, if only including other stuff - your main is at least 217 lines long! Including that, and telling us where the line it "doesn't like" comes from would be a start.

Comment: @NickJohnson In my main method I am not calling any functions from the files I included. There is some code, but it is not related with what I am trying to do know. My problem is that after including the FSIO.c file, even though I am not calling any functions from that file it gives the error mentioned previously after compiling. Again, is there a way to include a file to my question? I am not able to put the code from the FSIO.c file as an Edit because it is too long.

Comment: Don't worry about the error yet. Start eliminating all the warnings, from the top down. Chances are, some of the warnings are actually important (though under-appreciated, warnings are actually *always* important).

Comment: Is `FISO.c` part of your project, or a standard library of some sort?

Comment: @NickJohnson It is part of the MDD library. The MDD library can be found in MLA, by Microchip (http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/devtools/mla/legacy-mla.html). I have downloaded the Legacy version, because the current MLA doesn't support PIC18 microprocessors.

Comment: I suspect that, since the compiler gives three warnings for "unknown pragma udata" in FSIO.c, that FSIO.c was written for a different compiler that does recognize "udata" as a valid pragma.  You may have to "translate" the file to suit your current compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Conventions for inline assembly in PIC microcontrollers are different based on the compiler. It's very likely you're working with code that expects a different compiler. Try replacing this:

> _asm TBLRDPOSTINC _endasm

with this:

> asm(TBLRDPOSTINC)

Comment: I think the compiler that this version was written for is C18. I am using XC8. I tried replacing the inline assembly code with what you suggested. The error changed from:
`FSIO.c:7983: error: (195) expression syntax`
to:
`FSIO.c:7983: error: (318) string expected
FSIO.c:7983: error: (194) ")" expected
FSIO.c:7983: error: (312) ";" expected`

Comment: I changed it to:
`#asm 
   TBLRDPOSTINC
#endasm`
instead and it compiles

Comment: You should mark this answer as the solution if it helped.